# Asking emacs for default directory path "once"

Tags: emacs, directory, elisp

I want to have a variable that keeps the default directory a user enters and keep using it throughout the run of emacs.

Basically, when the user executes a custom command, the prompt will ask for a default directory path to execute the command (only once) and whenever the user calls the same command emacs uses the same path onward.

How can I program that snippet of code in lisp?

I basically want this code in the igrep library to accept the input from user once and not ask again:

```
(defvar default-files-string-new "*.[sch]")
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)
  "Read and return a file name pattern from the minibuffer.
If `current-prefix-arg' is '(16) or '(64), read multiple file name
patterns and return them in a list.  Optional PROMPT-PREFIX is
prepended to the \"File(s): \" prompt."
  (let* ((default-files (igrep-default-files))
     (default-files-string (mapconcat 'identity default-files " "))
     (insert-default-directory igrep-insert-default-directory)
     (file (igrep-read-file-name
        (igrep-prefix prompt-prefix
                  (if default-files
                  (format "File(s) [default: %s]: "
                      default-files-string)
                "File(s): "))
        nil (if default-files default-files-string "") nil nil
        'igrep-files-history))
     (files (list file)))
    (if (or igrep-read-multiple-files
        (and (consp current-prefix-arg)
         (memq (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
               '(16 64))))
    (let* ((key (igrep-default-key 'exit-minibuffer
                       minibuffer-local-completion-map
                       "\r"))
           (prompt
        (igrep-prefix prompt-prefix
                  (if igrep-verbose-prompts
                  (format "File(s): [Type `%s' when done] "
                      (key-description key))
                "File(s): "))))
      (while (and (setq file
                (igrep-read-file-name prompt
                          nil "" nil nil
                          'igrep-files-history))
              (not (equal file "")))
        (setq files (cons file files)))))
    (mapcar (lambda (file)
          (if (file-directory-p file)
          ;; really should map expand-file-name over default-files:
          (expand-file-name (if default-files default-files-string-new "*")
                    file)
        file))
        (nreverse files))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "custom command"? A function of your writing?

Comment: I mean a function that I am adding in .emacs.
Here is what I am trying to do: I am cutomizing a "grep" command that defaults to where the "user" say the main folder to grep in is and just use that variable onward without keep asking the user for the path of the main folder recursively.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a custom variable for the sane default, and then have the user enter the path or accept the default on the first call.

```
(defcustom default-path "/tmp/foo" "Path")
(setq current-path nil)


(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (unless current-path
    (setq current-path
          (read-from-minibuffer 
           (format "Path [%s]" default-path) nil nil t nil default-path)))
  (message "Path is: %s" current-path))
```

The first time you do M-x foo, it prompts for the path.  A common idiom is to allow the user to specify a prefix argument when they want to change the value (after the first time.)  This code will have the desired effect:

```
(defun foo (choose)
  (interactive "P")
  (when (or choose (not current-path))
    (setq current-path
          (read-from-minibuffer 
           (format "Path [%s]" default-path) nil nil t nil default-path)))
  (message "Path is: %s" current-path))
```

Now doing M-x foo is the same as before, but C-0 M-x foo will prompt for a new value.
In your example, something like this will work.

```
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)   
  (interactive "P")  
  (when (or prompt-prefix (not current-path ))
    (setq current-path
          (read-file-name "Dir: " default-path nil t)))   
  (message (expand-file-name default-files-string-new current-path)))
```

Comment: Hi Sean...Thanks for the repsonse.
I am trying to modify the igrep-find functionality in the igrep.el package.
So I followed your instructions and did this:

(defvar default-files-string-new "*.[sch]")
(defvar default-path "~/source/" "Path")
(setq current-path nil)

(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)
  (interactive)
  (unless current-path
    (setq current-path
          (read-from-minibuffer 
           (format "Path [%s]" default-path) nil nil t nil default-path)))
  `(,(expand-file-name (concat current-path
                               default-files-string-new)))
  )

Comment: However I get this error:
Wrong type argument: sequencep, ~/source/

Comment: Hi Sean...
I tried the adjusted example.
I still see that the prompt asks to enter directory name, and even when I change the directory name, the next time around it asked with a default directory of the old one "~/source/"

Comment: Ok. So this worked:

(defcustom d-path "~/source/" "Path")
(setq current-path nil)
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)   
  (interactive "P")  
  (unless current-path
    (setq current-path
          (read-file-name "Dir: " d-path nil t)))
  `(,(expand-file-name (concat current-path
                               default-files-string-new))))

However, the user need to make sure to follow the directory name by / for the path to work.

Comment: I actually found another issue.
If I did not change the default path, current-path somehow picks a different path.
For example: if I did not change the default ~/source/ then the grep would be on ~/source/source/

Comment: You're not using prompt-prefix in the unless/when clause. Also, why are you using quasiquotes there?

Comment: This works for me:

(defvar default-files-string-new "*.[sch]")
(defcustom d-path "~/source/" "Path")
(setq current-path nil)
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)
  (interactive "P")
  (when (or prompt-prefix (not current-path))
    (setq current-path (read-file-name "Dir: " d-path nil t)))
  (message
   (prin1-to-string
    (expand-file-name (concat current-path default-files-string-new)))))

Comment: I had to use unless because as I stated the code keeps asking for the directory path. It needs to stop asking after the first time.
I tried your new code and again...it keeps asking for the path every time I perform grepping.

Answer (score 2):

You could use advices to do that:

```
(defvar wd-alist nil)

(mapc
 (lambda (function)
   (eval
    `(defadvice ,function (around ,(intern (format "%s-wd" function)) activate)
       (let ((wd (cdr (assoc ',function wd-alist))))
         (unless wd
           (setq wd (read-file-name "Default directory: "))
           (push (cons ',function wd) wd-alist))
         (let ((default-directory wd))
           ad-do-it)))))
 '(grep-find))
```

The variable `wd-list` stores the association `(FUNCTION . PATH)`. The list `mapc` iterate over are the advised functions. Now, when calling `find-grep`, it asks for the working directory (after interactive arguments, so you first have to type the pattern and enter...) and stores it in `wd-list` for further use. Now your `find-grep` are always done in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code of `sendmail-query-once`.
Although it's not very fashionable to do this sort of thing.
Usually package writers pick a sane default and let the user
customize it as they want.

Comment: thanks for the response.
I do actually want the user to have a default "sane" folder which he could keep or change. But after he accept/change I want the variable to be set until he terminates emacs all together.

The reason I need this is that when I work on a project, I have the source and header directories under the main directory. I want to always search both folders and so grep from the parent folder. Parent folder is unlikely to change, it stays permanent throughout the implementation of the project.